# Apply a custom function on a pandas dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, function

I have a pandas dataframe like this:

```
pd.DataFrame({
'gender': ['male', 'female', 'female', 'male', 'unknown'],
'height': [70, 61, 64, 73, 69]})
```

I am trying to write a custom function that applies summary statistics to men/women heights. I then want to apply that custom function on a pandas dataframe. **I am not looking for a lambda function**, has to be a custom one. My code:

```
def get_summary(height):
    if df['gender'] == 'male':
        summary = np.mean(height)
    elif df['gender'] == 'female':
        summary = np.sqrt(height)
    else:
        summary = np.max(height)
    return summary
```

I then want to apply this function and assign it to a new column called "summary". Code:

```
df['summary'] = df['height'].apply(get_summary)
```

The error message I receive:

> ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

Comment: your function signature is incorrect, because df is outside the scope of what you're passing it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First change for compare `height.name`, value is grouping column, here `gender` and pass to [`GroupBy.transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) for return output in `Series` with length like original `DataFrame`, so possible assign to new colum:

```
def get_summary(x):
    print (x)
    print (x.name)

    if x.name == 'male':
        summary = np.mean(x)
    elif x.name == 'female':
        summary = np.sqrt(x)
    else:
        summary = np.max(x)
    return summary

df['summary'] = df.groupby('gender')['height'].transform(get_summary)
print (df)
    gender  height   summary
0     male      70  71.50000
1   female      61   7.81025
2   female      64   8.00000
3     male      73  71.50000
4  unknown      69  69.00000
```

Comment: I don't understand what "height.name" is doing here? What do you mean by first change for compare?

Comment: @MichaelMathewsJr. - It is grouing value, so if use `df.groupby('gender')` then `.name` is first `male`, then `female` and last `unknown` here.

Comment: @MichaelMathewsJr. - Rather rename for `x`, becuse not relative to `height`

Comment: Does it have to be "name" or can I pass whatever here?

Comment: @MichaelMathewsJr. - It is `x.name` if use `def get_summary(x):`, because `x` is grouped `height` column, if change `def get_summary(group):` then need `group.name`

Comment: @MichaelMathewsJr. - Added `print (x)` and `print (x.name)` for possible check how working this solution.

Comment: I understand passing in x or group or whatever as my argument in the function. The problem I'm having is understanding why I need .name to follow it, is this a python method or something else?

Comment: @Michael Mathews Jr. Yop, you are right, it is attribute.

Comment: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.name.html